# JSON validation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

```
[[["您好世界","Hello world","N n h o sh ji "]],,"en"]
```

this is  json object: `contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue`

I want to get `你好世界`.
How do it ?

```
NSString *returnStr=[[[[contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue JSONValue] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] ;
```

do this ，error:

> JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x739f0c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}",
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Expected value while parsing array\" UserInfo=0x739f140 {NSUnderlyingError=0x739f120 \"Unrecognised leading character\", NSLocalizedDescription=Expected value while parsing array}"

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [syntax chart at json.org](http://www.json.org/), I would say it is illegal to have two commas in an array with nothing between them.  Your JSON is malformed.

```
[[["您好世界","Hello world","N n h o sh ji "]],,"en"]
                                              ^^ not allowed!
```

Edit:  Just to prove my point, here is a [JSON validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/).